# Create a bulk job using JSforce

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsforce, bulk-api-v2

I am trying to create a bulk api query job using jsforce and nodejs. Below is the method i am calling after getting the access token. But it is not creating the job. Is the below way correct to create a query job.

```
function createBulkApiQueryJob( sfClient, res ) {
  const query = {
    "operation": "query",
    "query": "SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 10",
    "contentType": "CSV",
    "columnDelimiter": "CARET",
    "lineEnding": "CRLF"
  }
  var job = sfClient.bulk.createJob( "Account", "query" );
  var batch = job.createBatch();
  batch.execute( query );
  console.log( batch.Id );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's documented here how to make a bulk query

**To pipe to a file use below**

```
var fs = require('fs');
conn.bulk.query("SELECT Id, Name, NumberOfEmployees FROM Account")
 .stream().pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./accounts.csv'));
```

**To use in your node.js code**

```
 conn.bulk.query("SELECT Id, Name, NumberOfEmployees FROM Account")
  .on('record', function(rec) { console.log(rec); })
  .on('error', function(err) { console.error(err); });
```

**Update**

Note that `jsforce` does not support bulk query 2.0 operation to return jobId and `batchID` well

I suggest you use [bulk API v2.0](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/introduction_bulk_api_2.htm) and build your own npm module.

I have something started in my repo [here](https://github.com/msrivastav13/sfmetadataDependency). Check [here](https://github.com/msrivastav13/sfmetadataDependency/blob/master/src/commands/mdcapi/bulk/query.ts) to explore more

Comment: Hi Mohith.. Hope u r doing well. Saw all your videos very informative.. Here what i am trying to do is create a bulk query job which will query in batch and return the job id and batch ids. Later i can use the jobId to get the results . I dont want to store it in local.

Comment: @hellraizer Just looked into the jsforce. Seems like it does not support v2.0 well. I suggest you take a look at the sample repo I have shared.